# What is the mysterious power wielded by Johnny & Cassie Cage?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In the semi-reboot of the Mortal Kombat franchise, Mortal Kombat X, the story begins with a flashback. Among other things, we see Johnny Cage suddenly

> develop a new ability wherein he glows green and appears "super-charged" with some kind of mystical energy.

He is never able to do it again, apparently, although twenty years later his daughter Cassie shows the same ability and uses it to

> defeat Shinnok in his demonic form, thus saving reality.

Both Raiden and Shinnok referred to this ability only as "the power". **Has this "power" been explained or further developed in the time since?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has never really been explained. The best description comes from *Mortal Kombat X*, in which Johnny Cage mentions that Raiden told him that he is

> descended from some Mediterranean war cult. "Bred as warriors for the gods."

[image: screenshot of Johnny Cage explaining the origin of his power]

The recently released *Mortal Kombat 11* explores the pasts of some the characters -- including Johnny Cage, whose younger self knows the power (see, e.g. [this video](https://youtu.be/dbbVR7zsYYk?t=241) in which the younger Johnny Cage uses it against his older self in story mode). However, the power is only mentioned in passing (e.g. [Jacqui Briggs tells the younger Jax that "the Cages are born with crazy magic powers"](https://youtu.be/GIuC-UkEMuA?t=1200)) and no further explanation of it is given.

[Johnny Cage's page on the Mortal Kombat wiki](https://mortalkombat.fandom.com/wiki/Johnny_Cage) is limited to the same information about the origin of his power, and the [answer to a similar question on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/216027/85897) merely quotes the same wiki article.